# When and how should I use std::predicate

Tags: c++, c++20, predicate

I am trying to constrain a Callable to return a boolean when evaluated. I have been trying to use the concept [`std::predicate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/predicate), but it does not seem to do what I want it to do.

So I defined my own concept, that is invokable and returns something convertible to a boolean. But again, I struggle understanding what I can or can not do with it, and I wonder what are the actual use cases of `std::predicate`?

```cpp
#include<concepts>
#include<string>

template<class F, class... Args>
concept Predicate = std::invocable<F, Args...> &&
                    std::convertible_to<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>, bool>;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
 constexpr Predicate auto f1 = [](){return true;}; // ok
 constexpr std::predicate auto f2 = [](){return true;}; // ok
 constexpr int x = 34;
 constexpr Predicate auto f3 = [x](){ return x==42;}; // ok

 // Pas ok:  error: deduced initializer does not satisfy placeholder constraints
 //constexpr Predicate auto f4 = [](auto x){ return x==42;}; 
 //constexpr std::predicate auto f5 = [](auto x){ return x==42;};
}
```

Comment: `auto x` means any type can be here. There are no guarantees that the type will be comparable to an `int`. If you factor in the fact that lambdas are just anonymous classes with an `operator()` overload, and this basically defines a template function, for the overload, then the issue should be fairly obvious.

Comment: Are you asking why the last two examples don't work or are you asking what the difference between your `Predicate` and `std::predicate` is or are you asking what typical use cases for the latter are? These seem different questions to me. The current answer for example answers the first of these questions.

Comment: For comparison: [`constexpr std::predicate<int> auto f5 = [](auto x){ return x==42;};
}`](https://godbolt.org/z/jEobWdKKG) compiles...

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you! I was more asking for the typical use of std::predicate, as my Predicate concept was an attempt to have something that works in my use case.

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you! To be sure, in this example, what does the `int` in `std::predicate<int>` refers to ? The argument type or the return type?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you, it explains a ton. I got lost with what the compiler knows and does not know. So if I replace my `auto x` by a known type that should fix one part of the problem :)

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler Function arguments, see [`std::predicate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/predicate).

Comment: @Aconcagua ty, I already had checked the documentation :) I was asking because the first template argument in the concept description is the callable `F` and I regularly get lost with functions signatures, so I wanted to be sure!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a function that takes a "thing that can be called". It must be a "thing that can be called with some set of arguments of known (at the time of the declaration) types". That's why `std::predicate` takes a set of arguments in addition to the potential callable type.

Your first examples work because you didn't give the predicate concept any arguments and your functions also didn't take any parameters. So an empty argument list matches the empty parameter list.